# Getting error in child while doing mapping of two components in angular 5 and trying to populate menumodel in child

Tags: angular

I am very new in angular. I am trying to achieve as menubar is populated from home and menumodel is bound with home.component.html but I have another tab applyTab which show some value from tree structure at toggle. so I have to populate one submenu if applytab is opened and the same value shown from the node. I am trying to populate menumodel in apply tab and want show value while calling a method which is being called already in the apply tab. I got this error while doing the mapping.

Below is my current approach

in apply Tab

```
import { HomeComponent } from 'app/home/home.component';


@Input() public home: HomeComponent;

this.home.menuModel =  this.items = [{
  label: 'Add',
  items: [{
    label: 'Tree', 
  },
    { label: 'Show ID', 
    command: (event) => {
     this.toggleNodeDisplay();
  }
  }
  ]
}
];
```

I am getting this below error while doing mapping of two components.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type HomeComponent is part
>   of the declarations of 2 modules: HomeModule and ApplyModule! Please
>   consider moving HomeComponent to a higher module that imports
>   HomeModule and ApplyModule. You can also create a new NgModule that
>   exports and includes HomeComponent then import that NgModule in
>   HomeModule and ApplyModule. Error: Type HomeComponent is part of the
>   declarations of 2 modules: HomeModule and ApplyModule! Please consider
>   moving HomeComponent to a higher module that imports HomeModule and
>   ApplyModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and
>   includes HomeComponent then import that NgModule in HomerModule and
>   ApplyModule.
>
> at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._addTypeToModule (compiler.js:15373)
>       at eval (compiler.js:15245)
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15236)
>       at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34226)
>       at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34187)
>       at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:34081)
>       at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:230)
>       at eval (core.js:6589)
>       at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._addTypeToModule (compiler.js:15373)
>       at eval (compiler.js:15245)
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15236)
>       at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34226)
>       at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34187)
>       at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:34081)
>       at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:230)
>       at eval (core.js:6589)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:824)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
>       at eval (zone.js:873)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4747)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
>       at Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
>       at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:503)
>       at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)
>       defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:1427
>       ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1488
>       next @ core.js:5503
>       schedulerFn @ core.js:4342
>       SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:239
>       SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:186
>       Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:127
>       Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:91
>       Subject.next @ Subject.js:56
>       EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:4322
>       (anonymous) @ core.js:4778
>       ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:392
>       Zone.run @ zone.js:142
>       NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:4704
>       onHandleError @ core.js:4778
>       ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:396
>       Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:158
>       _loop_1 @ zone.js:702
>       api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone.js:711
>       drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:610
>       ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:503
>       invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
>       globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566

Answer (score 0):

Basically what this error means is that your `HomeComponent` has been declared in both `HomeModule` and in `ApplyModule`.

A component should only be declared in one module.

You can remove the declaration of your `HomeComponent` from both these modules add add it in the `AppModule` and import both the modules in your `AppModule`.

This way, your error will be resolved.

Comment: If I remove then I get this error. menuModel is property of home.

    ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'menuModel' of undefined
    at ApplyComponent.ngOnInit (apply-component.ts:67)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12401)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13928)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13871)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14764)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14705)

Comment: Can u create a stackblitz or plnkr so that I can look  at the code?

Comment: Actually project architecture is different so unable to replicate same because there is business condition to show at menubar I am trying to use this approach which is not working because they are reading items and label from json through service
 this.menuService.getMenu('assets/data/home/home-menu.json')
        .subscribe(
          res => this.menuModel = res,
 but command event ( command: (event) =>) works only in ts file  by this approach https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/menumodel
Do you think can it be achieved with the existing scenario?